# My Sumif and Xlookup work but sometimes it crashes and says "Argument must be in range"

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs, xlookup

I am summarising data using the following formula

```
=SUMIFS(XLOOKUP($B57,Actuals!$C:$C,Actuals!D:DC),XLOOKUP("Date",Actuals!$C:$C,Actuals!C:DB),">="&Configuration!$B$10,XLOOKUP("Date",Actuals!$C:$C,Actuals!C:DB),"<"&Configuration!$C$10)
```

The first Xlookup defines the row, based on a specific value, whilst the second and third Xlookup find the columns if the date of the column is between two dates (as defined in the configuration tab).

I also want to return the value in the column in front of the column where the date matches the xlookup.

The formula works perfectly and brings through the correct numbers. However sometimes when I update other areas of the workbook the formulas crash and it returns a "#Error' (Argument must be within range).

Why is this happening and how can I stop google sheets from doing this?

I'm not sure why this is happening as the formula works originally and the ranges are the same length.

To get it working again I have to change to the first ">" to ">=" and then back to ">".

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: SUMIFS(). FILTER(). QUERY() may work. Share sample data as well as desired output.